# How can I insert array data into MySQL in Perl?

Tags: perl, insert, dbi

I parse a text file with the script below.

How to insert the array data to MySQL table?

I already learned Perl MySQL DBI connect method. And I can connect to local MySQL DB successfully. I can create the table with MySQL command line.

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    my @rocks = split(/\s+/, $_);

    foreach my $rock (@rocks) {  

    $rock = "\t$rock "; # put a tab in front of each element of @rocks 

    $rock .= "\n"; # put a newline on the end of each  

    print $rock ;
    } 
} 

__DATA__ 
A B C D
E F G H
```

I want the **table** browse result.

```
        Item1  Item2  Itme3 Item4

        A       B      C       D

        E       F      G       H
```

Comment: Your comments are not in sync with the code: Where is `@rocks`? Your variable names lie to the reader: `$array` is not an array ref as one might expect. Plus: **`s/talbe/table/`**

Comment: Hi Sinan, I revised my post.Thanks for your nice comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    'DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost',
    'root',
    'YOUR_PASSWORD',
    { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 },
);

my $sql = 'INSERT INTO foo (Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

while (<DATA>){
    chomp;
    my @vals = split /\s+/, $_;
    $sth->execute(@vals);
}

__END__
A B C D
E F G H
```

Comment: Hi FM, it works very well. Could you please give me more dissecion about `RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1` ?, I can't understand it. Thank you.

Comment: @Nano HE: Take a look at manuals http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI. Everything is described there